# Get next purchase date for specific set of users

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have subscriptions table shown as below

```
+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
| user_id | purchase_id | start_date |  end_date  |
+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|       1 | 1A          | 2019-01-12 | 2019-01-22 |
|       1 | 1B          | 2019-01-24 | 2019-02-03 |
|       1 | 1C          | 2019-02-06 | 2019-02-16 |
|       1 | 1D          | 2019-03-12 | 2019-03-22 |
|       1 | 1E          | 2019-04-01 | 2019-04-11 |
|       2 | 2A          | 2019-02-12 | 2019-02-22 |
|       2 | 2B          | 2019-02-23 | 2019-03-05 |
|       2 | 2C          | 2019-03-06 | 2019-03-16 |
|       2 | 2D          | 2019-03-18 | 2019-03-28 |
|       3 | 3A          | 2019-02-12 | 2019-02-22 |
|       3 | 3B          | 2019-02-23 | 2019-03-05 |
|       3 | 3C          | 2019-03-06 | 2019-03-16 |
|       3 | 3D          | 2019-03-18 | 2019-03-28 |
|       4 | 4A          | 2019-04-10 | 2019-04-20 |
|       4 | 4B          | 2019-04-25 | 2019-05-05 |
|       4 | 4C          | 2019-05-13 | 2019-05-23 |
+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

It has information about when a user(`user_id`) bought particular subscription(`start_date`). Each purchase has a `purchase_id` associated with it.

I want to know what is the `start_date` of the next subscription that user has bought, only for certain set of `purchase_id`.These `purchase_id` are in the below table

```
+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
| user_id | purchase_id | start_date |  end_date  |
+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|       1 | 1B          | 2019-01-24 | 2019-02-03 |
|       2 | 2C          | 2019-03-06 | 2019-03-16 |
|       3 | 3D          | 2019-03-18 | 2019-03-28 |
+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

So for `user_id` = 1, I want to know what is the next `start_date`. But that `start_date` should be of the next purchase made after `purchase_id = 1B` (It is 1C in this case)

Similarly  for `user_id` = 2, I want to know what is the next `start_date`. But that `start_date` should be of the next purchase made after `purchase_id = 2C` (It is 2D in this case)

My desired result is as shown below

```
+---------+-------------+------------+------------+--------------------+------------------+
| user_id | purchase_id | start_date |  end_date  | Next_Purchase_date | Next_purchase_id |
+---------+-------------+------------+------------+--------------------+------------------+
|       1 | 1B          | 2019-01-24 | 2019-02-03 | 2019-02-06         | 1C               |
|       2 | 2C          | 2019-03-06 | 2019-03-16 | 2019-03-18         | 2D               |
|       3 | 3D          | 2019-03-18 | 2019-03-28 | NULL               | NULL             |
+---------+-------------+------------+------------+--------------------+------------------+
```

I was able to get the next purchase dates with below code

```
SELECT A.*, 
LEAD(start_date) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY start_date) as Next_Purchase_date,
LEAD(purchase_id) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY start_date) as Next_Purchase_id
FROM Table1 A
```

But how can I get `next_purchase_date` only for certain `purchase_id`s ?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0500a/2)

Comment: *I want to know what is the start_date of the next subscription that user has bought, only for certain set of purchase_id. These purchase_id are in the below table*: do you actually have a second table that stores the records for which you want the next purchase? (this table is not showing in your fiddle).

Comment: Practically the table 2 is a subset of table 1 basis some conditions. For the ease I have updated the fiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to filter the `LEAD()`.  But if you add a `WHERE` clause, it will impact the window function.

So, use a subquery and filter *after* calculating the `LEAD()`:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM (SELECT A.*, 
             LEAD(start_date) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY start_date) as Next_Purchase_date,
             LEAD(purchase_id) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY start_date) as Next_Purchase_id
      FROM Table1 A
     ) a JOIN
     B b
     ON b.user_id = a.user_id AND
        b.purchase_id = a.purchase_id;
```

Note:  you might actually want `b left join a` in this case, if there is a possibility that some rows in `b` don't have corresponding rows in `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you do have a second table, say `table2` that stores the records for which you want to see the next purchases, you could compute the `lead`s in a subquery, and then join it with the second table:

```
    select t1.*
    from (
        select
            t1.*, 
            lead(start_date) over(partition by user_id order by start_date) next_purchase_date,
            lead(purchase_id) over(partition by user_id order by start_date) next_purchase_id
        from table1 t1
    ) t1
    inner join table2 t2
        on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
        and t1.purchase_id = t2.purchase_id
        and t1.start_date = t2.start_date
        and t1.end_date = t2.end_date
```